# How does MXML read its own program, e.g., a function inside a mxml file?

Tags: apache-flex, flex4, mxml

When there is a property, a method, and some components in a mxml file, how does it read these lines? When there is some statements inside a method (e.g., Alert.show ('Hellow World')), 
mxml read them first, but do not execute them; then after this method is called from somewhere, then the method is executed, right?

Answer (score 1):

When the compiler compiles an mxml file, it creates an intermediate file that contains ActionScript that has been generated from the mxml.  You can see exactly what the generated ActionScript looks like by adding this to your compiler arguments: `-keep-generated-actionscript` Hope that helps.